# Extract words between two specific characters or number

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to extract the two specific words from excel cell ie: cell `A1` contains data

```
{"defvcision":"DISASDEE","reascdwon":"labwcel","cowcddcents":"SwcA:Ercwdcror:CwcOwccPcewS:SewellerApcwecpewcal-BwerLR:2/24/2020 : 306973918 @ snedcharo"}
```

Now I want to extract `306973918` and snedcharo from cell. These to values will be dynamic in other cells ie `A2` `A3`...

I have tried formula

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH(":",A1) + 1, SEARCH(":",A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1) - SEARCH(":",A1) - 1)
```

but that is not working.

Comment: Parsing JSON using pure Excel is going to be a headache (and also error-prone).  If you need to do this within Excel, I suggest using VBA which should have some JSON library available.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Can you share me the VBA script which can work for this.

Comment: I can't because I have never worked with JSON from VBA before.  If you Google around, you will probably find usable code on the very first page of search results.

Comment: What if i need ti extract the number of 10 characters starting from 03(10 characters) or 3(9 characters)

Comment: If you want to parse simple JSON (not multi-nested) in vba use Tim Hall's VBA-JSON on Git-Hub... I am using it and really useful ..... For the formula try ..... `MID(D5,1,FIND("@",MID(D5,FIND("2020 :",D5,1)+7,LEN(D5)),1)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

if all the cells are kinda the same format you can also use text to columns on this cell with delimited and space and your number will be on "C" column

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use UDF.
In order to define UDF you need to write simple function in worksheets module, like in below picture:
[image]

Then you can use it in worksheet like below:
[image]

Below is the function code, which you can adjust to your needs:

```
Function ExtractText(text As String)
    text = StrReverse(text)
    colonIdx = InStr(1, text, ":")
    apostropheIdx = InStr(1, text, """")
    text = Mid(text, apostropheIdx + 1, colonIdx - apostropheIdx - 2)
    ExtractText = StrReverse(text)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In `A2`, formula copied down to `A3` :

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A$1,"""}","")," @","")," ",REPT(" ",99)),(3-ROW(A1))*99),99))
```

[image]